# How does chrome know that my login was sucessfull?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

If I login on any new site, google chrome asks me if I want it to save my password.
My initial thought was that it simply watches form submits, but the prompt doesn't show when the login fails because of a wrong password.

So how does it know? Is it looking for URL changes or something more complex?

(Context: I'm working on a chrome extension that alerts you whenever you enter a weak password. Simply adding an 'onsubmit' event handler to the login form doesn't work for me, because some of the checks run asynchronously. I also tried using event.preventDefault() and asynchronously calling the form submit again later, but that doesn't seem to work for some sites.)

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that it watches for URL changes after submit. I noticed with some slow-loading websites that the password save dialog is shown only after the subsequent page begins to load. On the other hand, the dialog is not displayed when the same login page is simply reloaded (with or without additional args) which usually happens on bad login.

But this is an educated guess only.

Comment: upvoted - I've noticed this behavior too. Sometimes when I get a password incorrect, some websites redirect me to another page. When this happens, chrome offers to save my password. Still a guess, but I think we can confirm by digging around Chromium source code (which is open source)